# Unable to understand namedtuple syntax

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to use `collections.namedtuple`. I went through the documentation and encountered following syntaxes.

```
Person = namedtuple('Person', 'name,age,gender')
anup = Person(name='Anup', age=21, gender='male')
```

Following also works fine

```
Person = namedtuple('Person', 'name age gender')
anup = Person(name='Anup', age=21, gender='male')
```

I came across following syntax which was something like this.

```
Person = namedtuple('Person', 'name age gender' 'address phone')
```

Ref:https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/textsum/batch_reader.py#L29

If I try to do the following

```
anup = Person(name='Anup', age=21, gender='male', address='xyz', phone='1234')
```

it throws an error stating

```
TypeError: __new__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'gender'
```

but this seems to be working absolutely fine.

```
anup = Person(name='Anup', age=21, genderaddress='xyz', phone='1234')
```

I am unable to understand the syntax, and how the two attributes have merged together.

Comment: You did not write a comma between `gender'` and `'address` so Python concats the two strings...

Comment: String literals are joined on juxtaposition

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem did you have a look at the link? Why is that thing done if it will not work correctly?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem `namedtuple` only takes a single argument for the list of attributes, so string concat is expected. The issue is the lack of space `' '` after gender or before address, so that this string is interpreted correctly instead of `genderaddress`.

Comment: @utkbansal: because Python sees `namedtuple('Person', 'name age genderaddress phone')`. So it thinks there is one field named `genderaddress`.

Comment: In the link you referred to, there's a space at the end of the first string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because this:

```
Person = namedtuple('Person', 'name age gender' 'address phone')
```

Is equivalent to this:

```
Person = namedtuple('Person', 'name age genderaddress phone')
```

[Here](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literal-concatenation) is the documentation:

> Multiple adjacent string or bytes literals (delimited by whitespace),
>   possibly using different quoting conventions, are allowed, and their
>   meaning is the same as their concatenation. Thus, `"hello" 'world'` is
>   equivalent to `"helloworld"`.

So note, this is just part of the python syntax, and nothing special about `namedtuple`.

In the link, we have the following:

```
ModelInput = namedtuple('ModelInput',
                        'enc_input dec_input target enc_len dec_len '
                        'origin_article origin_abstract')          ^
```

Notice the space.

Comment: Note, this is a general rule of Python syntax, and nothing to do with namedtuple specifically.